# Invoking shell script with -option and parameters

Tags: shell-script

I need to invoke a shell script `test.sh` in the following manner:

```
./test.sh -run/-rerun  username password
```

How to check if they have passed `-run` or `-rerun` option inside my shell script?

Answer (score 8):

A common approach is to use [`getopt`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) utility to break up the command line options passed to the script for easy parsing. `getopt` supports both short (single character) and long (multiple character) options with or without arguments. When `getopt` is invoked it is passed two kinds of parameters: options which modify the way `getopt` will parse options, and the parameters of the calling script which are to be parsed.

The most essential options for specifying how `getopt` will parse the remaining arguments are the following:

- `-o, --options shortopts` The short options to be parsed. The `shortopts` argument to this option is a string of characters that should be recognized as short options. An option character with a required argument should be followed with a colon `:`, while an option with an optional argument should be followed by two colons `::`. For example, the `shortopts` string `ab:c::` corresponds to the following recognized options `-a`, `-b arg`, `-c` and `-c arg`. Note that if this option is not specified, `getopt` will treat the first option that does not start with `-` (and is not an option argument) as the `shortopts` string.
- `-l, --longoptions longopts` The long options to be parsed. More than one option may be specified at once, separating the option names with commas, or the `-l` option may be given more than once. Required and optional arguments are indicated as with the `-o` option with a `:` or `::` following the option name.
- `-a, --alternative` A common convention, especially with [GNU](http://gnu.org) software, is that long options are prepended with two dashes, e.g. `--run`. The `-a` option tells `getopt` to allow long options to start with a single `-` character.
- `-q,--quiet` If `getopt` encounters an unrecognized option or a missing required argument in the parameters to be parsed, it will print a message of the form `getopt: unrecognized option '[option name]'` or `getopt: option '[option name'] requires an argument` to `stderr`, generate the normal output to `stdout` and exit with a non-zero status. The `-q` option can be used to suppress the error messages.
- `-n, --name progname` This option can be used to specify the program name that will be used by `getopt` when reporting the abovementioned errors.

The first non-option parameter (that is not an option argument or treated as `shortopts` string as described above) is treated by `getopt` as the start the parameter list that is to be parsed. The start of these parameters can also be indicated with `--`, in which case the first parameter after the `--` is treated as the start of the parameter list to be parsed.

The normal output of of `getopt` is an expanded list of the recognized options as follows:

- Short options given together, e.g. `-abc`, are expanded to individual options, i.e. `-a -b -c`.
- If `-a` is specified as an option to `getopt`, long options starting with a single dash, e.g. `-foo`, get prefixed with an additional dash, i.e. `--foo`.
- Required and optional arguments to options are quoted, e.g. `-b arg` becomes `-b 'arg'`, `--foo arg` and `--foo=arg` become `--foo 'arg'`.
- Any remaining arguments are quoted and separated from the options with `--`.

The advantage of the expansion is that it is easier to parse the broken up options as there are fewer cases left to consider. An example of command line option parsing using `getopt` as specified in the question is given below:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPTS=`getopt -a -l run -l rerun -- "$0" "$@"`
if [ $? != 0 ] # There was an error parsing the options
then
  exit 1 
fi

eval set -- "$OPTS"

while true; do
  case "$1" in
    --run) echo "option --run specified"; shift;;
    --rerun) echo "option --rerun specified"; shift;;
    --) shift; break;;
  esac
done

echo "Args:" 
for arg # Process remaining arguments
do
  echo $arg
done
```

**Explanation:**

```
OPTS=`getopt -a -l run -l rerun -- "$0" "$@"`
```

Here we set the `OPTS` variable to hold the output of the `getopt` invocation. The arguments passed to `getopt` here are built-in variables set by the shell, `bash` in this example. The `$0` holds the name of script and `$@` holds all the command line arguments passed to the script, individually quoted. `getopt` will process the arguments according to the specified options. In this example `getopt` will recognize the long options `--run` and `--rerun` with no arguments. Thanks to the`-a` option `getopt` will also recognize the forms `-run` and `-rerun`. The result of the `getopt` invocation is an expanded list of arguments. For example, a script invocation such as `test.sh -run username password` gets expanded by the shell to the `getopt` invocation `getopt -a -l run -l rerun -- "test.sh" "-run" "username" "password"`. `getopt` in turn will output the expanded arguments `--run -- 'username' 'password'`.

---

```
if [ $? != 0 ] # There was an error parsing the options
then
  exit 1 
fi
```

The built-in variable `$?` holds the return value of the most recently executed command. A non-zero return value indicates that `getopt` encountered an error.

---

```
eval set -- "$OPTS"
```

This will essentially replace the original command line arguments passed to the script with the expanded arguments output by `getopt`.

---

```
while true; do
  case "$1" in
    --run) echo "option --run specified"; shift;;
    --rerun) echo "option --rerun specified"; shift;;
    --) shift; break;;
  esac
done
```

The loop will process each positional parameter in turn, starting with the `$1`, the first one . After the `getopt` expansion, there are only three cases to consider. At the end of processing each case `shift` will shift the positional parameters so that `$2` becomes `$1`, `$3` becomes `$2` and so forth. Due to this, the positional parameter `$1` will hold a new value on each iteration of the loop.

If the option being processed would take an required argument, the argument value could be accessed in the `case` statement through the positional parameter `$2`. When the option and its argument have been processed the postional parameter would need to be shifted by 2 to get rid of both the option **and** the argument.

As `getopt` outputs a `--` after the recognized options, before the remaining arguments, the `--` case indicates the end of the option list and the termination condition of the `while` loop.

---

```
echo "Args:" 
for arg # Process remaining arguments
do
  echo $arg
done
```

`for arg` is short for `for arg in "$@"`. Note that after the `while` loop, due the the `shift` at each case, `$@` now only holds the remaining arguments that followed `--` in the `getopt` output.

Comment: Thanks. it worked .. but now if i am not passing --option while invoking the shell script by default it should echo that default option has been chosen.How will i put it in case statement ??

Comment: @suni: One approach would be to define a variable holding a value indicating the default option value before the `while` loop. Set the variable in the `case` statement depending on which option is triggered. After the loop completes and all options have been processed you can check the value of the variable. If it still has the default value, no option modifying the was specified and you could `echo` a message indicating that the script proceeds with default behaviour.

Comment: why u have used shift in the code

Comment: @suni: `shift` shifts the positional parameters so that `$1` will point to a new option each iteration of the `while` loop. I have updated the answer with a more detailed explanation of `getopt` behaviour and each step of the sample script.